# Find a Pouchdb document by date

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

i created the db and inserted the records below is my doc

```
 var doc = {
      _id: Sno,
      Date:date,
      time:Time,
      trip : Trip,
      triptype:TripType,
      vechicleNo: VechicleNo,
      customer: Customer,
      vechicletType: VechicleType,
     
   };
```

now i want to get the values based on date selection 
[image]

on selecting date i want to get all values based on date
i used the find plugin but it display doc as 0 even if there is data in particular date

here is my find plugin code

```
\\getting the date value on select
var saledate = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
   console.log(saledate);

   db.createIndex({
      index: {
        fields: ['Date']
      }
   });

   db.find({
        selector: {
          Date: saledate,  // assigning date value to the selector
        },
      });
   }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
   });
```

can any any one help me with code

Comment: Is `startdate` an input type= date? This matters because pouchDB will index a Date object with `toISOString()`. The html input type = date `value` doesn't have a time component, e.g. "2021-06-23T13:20:03.069Z" is not "2021-06-23".

Comment: yes  `startdate` is type = date  and date value in doc is input type = text

Comment: want to covert the `startdate `to string?